# Undefined variable: Battery in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have created a pie chart in Laravel which is working fine, but when I implement it inside of a project I get an error.

> Undefined variable: Battery (View:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\webpro3\resources\views\showrecord.blade.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var analytics = <?php echo $Battery; ?>
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('showrecord','ShowrecordController');
```

**Controller**

```php
public function piechart()
{
    $data = DB::table('importpdfs')
        ->select(
            DB::raw('Battery as Battery'),
            DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
        ->groupBy('Battery')
        ->where('ST', '>=', 7)
        ->orWhere('SAS', '>=', 120)
        ->orWhere('NPR', '>=', 90)
        ->get();

    $array[] = ['Battery', 'Number'];

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $array[++$key] = [$value->Battery, $value->number];
    }

    return view('showrecord')->with('Battery', json_encode($array));
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: How do you make this resource route match that method in the controller? Is it possible that there is another route or controller's method that returns the view without the variable?

Comment: m new to it can u guide me what to do to tackle it

Comment: try `$Battery = json_encode($array); return view('showrecord', compact('Battery'))`

Comment: try adding this route before the resource route you posted: `Route::get('foo/bar', 'ShowrecordController@piechart');`, then in your browser go to http://your-domain/foo/bar

Comment: not  working remember the error is at here https://ibb.co/G3KzRQ0

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ output is: https://ibb.co/GCR1TrQ

Comment: ok, look in your controller which method are returning the same view, will have something like thit at the end: `return view('showrecord')`

Comment: for the index this method is working   return view('showrecord', compact('pdfdata', 'importpdfs'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this way.

In the piechart() method change the return line, to returning just the data:

```
public function piechart()
{
    // ...
    return json_encode($array);
}
```

And in the index() method assign the returned data from piechart() to a variable, then return the variable with the view adding 'Battery' inside compact():

```
public function index()
{
    // ...
    $Battery = $this->piechart();
    return view('showrecord', compact('pdfdata', 'importpdfs', 'Battery'));
}
```

Comment: Yes, sure. I did not know if it was going to work, that's why I did not explain it. A route of type resource corresponds with only some methods in the controller. That's why I found it strange that you came to a `piechart()` method with that route. From the questions in the comments I came to the conclusion that it was the `index()` method that was returning the view where the error was. Then I suggested that in the `piechart()` method you only return the data, to assign them to a variable in the `index()` method and from there you return the view with the variable.

Comment: Take a look in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers) to have a broader idea of how a resource type controller works